# TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not type

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api

I've run into a problem while coding an assignment for my high school cs class. I an pretty new to python, so please forgive me if I make any mistakes while explaining my program or the error. Also, I'm sure there are plenty of things I could do to optimize my program, but again, I am new.

The program essentially uses a command line menu to manipulate the data inside an API. Here is the program:

```
import requests
import json
import wikipedia
#from datetime import datetime

response = requests.get("https://data.nasa.gov/resource/y77d-th95.json")
meteorite_page = json.loads(response.text)

# Helper Functions
def get_meteorites(type = "all"):   
    if type == "all":
        names = [mtrt["name"] for mtrt in meteorite_page]
    else:
        names = [mtrt["name"] for mtrt in meteorite_page if type in mtrt["recclass"]]
        
    return names

def sort_by_feature(type):
    if type == "year":
        feature = [mtrt["year"] for mtrt in meteorite_page]   
    else:
        feature = [mtrt["mass"] for mtrt in meteorite_page]
        
    return feature
    
# Choice functions
def print_all():
    all_names = get_meteorites(type)
    for index, name in enumerate(all_names):
        print(f"{index + 1}: {name}")
    print(all_names)
    
def print_by_class():
    type = input("Enter a class (See this page for classification names/details --> stackoverflow made me take out this link): ").upper()
    all_names = get_meteorites(type)
    print(f"All {type} meteorites: ")
    for index, name in enumerate(all_names):
        print(f"{index + 1}: {name}")
    
def sort_by_year():
    all_years = sort_by_feature("year")
    for index, year in enumerate(all_years):
        print(f"{index + 1}: {year}")
    print(all_years)
    
def sort_by_mass():
    all_masses = sort_by_feature("mass")
    for index, mass in enumerate(all_masses):
        print(f"{index + 1}: {mass}")
    print(all_masses)
        
def meteorite_data():
    
    meteorite_name = input("Enter the name of a meteorite: ")
    
    for mtrt in meteorite_page:
        if meteorite_name in mtrt['name']:
            for key in mtrt:
                print(f"{key}: {mtrt[key]}")
    
    print("Wikipedia Summary: ")
    try:
        print(wikipedia.summary(f"{meteorite_name} (meteorite)"))
    except:
        print("No Wikipedia page could be found.")

# User interface
def start_interface():

    print("Meteorite Data Explorer")
    print("‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾")
   
    while True:
        print("̲M̲e̲n̲u̲ ̲")
        print("1. List the names of all Earth meteorite landings")
        print("2. See all meteorites in one class")
        print("3. Organize meteorites from oldest to newest")
        print("4. Organize meteorites from biggest to smallest")
        print("5. Access the data of an individual meteorite")
        print("0. Quit")
        choice = input("Select an option: ")
        
        if choice == "1":
            print_all()
        elif choice == "2":
            print_by_class()
            print('')
        elif choice == "3":
            sort_by_year()
            print('')
        elif choice == "4":
            sort_by_mass()
            print('')
        elif choice == "5":
            meteorite_data()
            print('')
        elif choice == "0":
            print("Exit")
            break
        else:
            print("That is not an option.")
            print("‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾")
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_interface()
```

The errors I am receiving are on option 1, 3 and 4.
The full error when I try to run option 1:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*****\*******\api_project.py", line 109, in <module>
    start_interface()
  File "C:\Users\*****\*******\api_project.py", line 87, in start_interface
    print_all()
  File "C:\Users\*****\*******\api_project.py", line 31, in print_all
    all_names = get_meteorites(type)
  File "C:\Users\*****\*******\api_project.py", line 15, in get_meteorites
    names = [mtrt["name"] for mtrt in meteorite_page if type in mtrt["recclass"]]
  File "C:\Users\*****\*******\api_project.py", line 15, in <listcomp>
    names = [mtrt["name"] for mtrt in meteorite_page if type in mtrt["recclass"]]
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not type
```

And the full error when I run options 3 and 4:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\*****\*******\api_project.py", line 106, in <module>
    start_interface()
  File "C:\Users\*****\*******\api_project.py", line 89, in start_interface
    sort_by_year()
  File "C:\Users\*****\*******\api_project.py", line 41, in sort_by_year
    all_years = sort_by_feature("year")
  File "C:\Users\*****\*******\api_project.py", line 20, in sort_by_feature
    feature = [mtrt["year"] for mtrt in meteorite_page]
  File "C:\Users\*****\*******\api_project.py", line 20, in <listcomp>
    feature = [mtrt["year"] for mtrt in meteorite_page]
KeyError: 'year'
```

The for option 3 and 4, the KeyError changes between 'year' and 'mass' respectively.
Any help would be appreciated, and I will answer all questions to the best of my ability.

Comment: What is `if type in mtrt["recclass"]` supposed to mean?

Comment: Don't use `type` as a variable name, it's the name of a built-invariable that holds the base of the type hierarchy.

Comment: The problem is here: `all_names = get_meteorites(type)` You never assigned `type`, so it's using the global variable. I think you wanted `all_names = get_meteorites("all")`

Comment: If type equals string? Edit: Look at Barmar answer.

Comment: @Barmar - Yes, that seemed to fix one of the problems. I changed all instances of 'type' to 'recclass' and where I called 'get_meteorites(type),' I changed 'type' to 'all,' like you said. But I am still getting the KeyError when I try options 3 and 4.

Comment: error shows that `mtrt` doesn't have `"year"`. You could at least check `print(mtrt)` to see what you have in this varialbe. If it is dictionary then you can also keys - `print( mtrt.keys() )`

Comment: using `requests` you can do `meteorite_page = response.json()`

Comment: it would be simpler and shorter if you would convert JSON to `pandas.DataFrame` - and you would have may function to sort it, filter it, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The `type` problem is because you wrote

```
all_names = get_meteorites(type)
```

This should be either

```
all_names = get_meteorites("all")
```

or

```
all_names = get_meteorites()
```

since the default is `"all"`.

The other errors are because some of the meteorites are missing the `year` or `mass` properties. You need to add checks for that to the list comprehensions.

```
def sort_by_feature(recclass):
    if recclass == "year":
        feature = [mtrt["year"] for mtrt in meteorite_page if "year" in mtrt]
    else:
        feature = [mtrt["mass"] for mtrt in meteorite_page if "mass" in mtrt]
        
    return feature
```

This will just skip the meteorites that don't have the specified feature.